# WPF: is it possible to send to convert another object?

Tags: wpf, binding, converters

So i have this simple `Label`:

```
<Label Name="lblFiles"
       Content="{Binding Path=(my.TotalFiles), Converter={StaticResource GaugeValueConverter}}"/>
```

And this `Converter`:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
     int val = (int)value;
     double percentage = ((double)MyData.TotalFiles/ MyData.TotalFilesInList) * 100;
     return val;
}
```

So this `Converter` return to my `Label` the correct value and this is working fine but i am wonder if i can send to this `Converter` another parameter: my `Progress-Bar` so instead of write another `Converter` i just update my `Progress-Bar` with my percentage property that i define in this `Converter`.

This is what i have try (fail..):

XAML:

```
Content="{Binding Path=(my.TotalFiles), Converter={StaticResource GaugeValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=myProgressBar}"
```

Converter:

```
ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar)parameter;
```

Comment: In your converter you are doing nothing. Percentage is not used. Also your progress bar should represent the progression of an "heavy" task? cause in that case you won't see anything, because the task will freeze your UI.

Comment: Percentage not using because i want to use it with my Progress-Bar

Comment: I did not find the other post...

Comment: In the Label.Content Binding the converter is pointless, because it just returns the source value, casted to int. You could better achieve that by setting the Label's ContentStringFormat property. For the ProgressBar use a MultiBinding with a multi-value converter as suggested in the answer to your previous question.

Comment: You asked the same thing yesterday basically, and you already received an answer

Comment: Yesterday i asked about another parameter, now i am asking about another controller